# Cartoon about robots that are controlled by humans

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, robots, mecha

The plot is that a team of 3 people a girl, a boy, and a short man with a funny haircut control robots and fight against a white alien that too can control robots. In the beginning I remember there was some kind of a test that a lot of people came and the prize was a strong mecha. The style was western-style animation.

The short guy in childhood was rescued by a man who controlled a mecha and the short man was amazed. He decided to be a pilot too but because he was short he could only be a guardian. The boy passed something like a test and he trained in organization area.

I remember there was an episode that showed how the alien came and was beaten by a primitive human who could control a bone robot.

Comment: In the future please don't [delete and repost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246496/58193) the same question. If you have information to add you can always [edit] the question!

Comment: @Imatabil - When did you watch this cartoon, and roughly when do you think it was made?